# IIS 7.5 Basic Authentication

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I am having problems with Basic Authentication in IIS 7.5.

I have:

- enabled Basic Authentication on my site
- disabled Anonymous Authentication on the same site
- Added an IIS user and allowed said user to the site
- Added read/write permissions for Basic Authentication on said site (feature delegation)

Its still not working. It prompts for username and password, but does not accept the user/pass i've created.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Added an IIS User" -> Do you mean *IIS Manager* user?

If so, these aren't real Windows users - just a username and a password in a text file somewhere: they don't have a SID or security tokens, and can't be used for Basic authentication. Not using the out-of-the-box configuration, anyway.

Create a (real) Windows user, and it'll be usable for Basic auth.

--

Edit: I just noticed you said something else - Feature Delegation doesn't describe permissions to the site *contents*, it's whether a non-Administrator can configure those features at a lower level within the site in a web.config file - essentially, which IIS feature icons are usable when they connect to the computer via the Management Service.

The answer is roughly the same, though:

- reset delegation to defaults (you didn't mean to change it; it's dangerous to change some of the delegation settings from defaults under these conditions)
- create a Windows user in Server Manager
- assign permissions to that Windows user either at the file system level, or using the URL Authorization feature

Comment: Thank you. Its working now. Also, undid the feature delegation.

Comment: Excellent! Glad you got it working.